# Image width and height inside <picture> tag?

Tags: html, css, seo, responsive, pagespeed

I have a problem with setting right width and height for the main **img src** inside  block.

```
<picture style="text-align: center; display: block;">
  <source srcset="https://www.ceramic-glazes.com/image/catalog/banners/ceramic-pigments.jpg" media="(min-width: 1200px)" width="1140" height="380">
  <source srcset="https://www.ceramic-glazes.com/image/catalog/banners/ceramic-pigments-600w.jpg" media="(min-width: 625px)" width="600" height="380">
  <source srcset="https://www.ceramic-glazes.com/image/catalog/banners/ceramic-pigments-320w.jpg" media="(max-width: 625px)" width="320" height="320">
  <img src="https://www.ceramic-glazes.com/image/catalog/banners/ceramic-pigments.jpg" alt="Ceramic pigments for Pottery for Ceramics Heraeus" width="100%" height="100%">
</picture>
```

1. If I leave it with **width="100%" height="100%"** visually is OK but Google search PageSpeed Insights reports bad **CLS**.
2. If I set the original size **width="1140" height="380"** all browsers but Chrome set these sizes on the image and visual is bad but **CLS is OK**!.
3. If I leave **img src** without width and height PageSpeed Insights returns  **Image elements do not have explicit width and height**  and **bad CLS**.

So any glue how to fix this issue?
Basically I want to show a different images for different screen sizes, so is there another way than  to do it?

You can check how it looks on our site here -> [ceramic glazes](https://www.ceramic-glazes.com/)

At Any product like [gold glaze for ceramics](https://www.ceramic-glazes.com/liquid-bright-gold-1-gram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy, simply double state your property rules for your dimensions, with the final rule being what you *really* want.

So, something like this

```
.image {
width: 100px;  //gives good CLS/Lighthouse (initial)
width: 100%;   //gives the desired display result (final)
}
```

This is also a form of redundancy for supporting old browsers, where you load the old and more common rules first, with the *bleeding-edge* stuff last.
If the browser does not understand the rules, it discards them.
HTH.

Comment: OMG! I can't believe how simple is this solution! I didn't know that I can use double rules in the same property! Thank mate!